# How to copy a zip with symbolic link in OS X?

Tags: macos, symlink, zip

I am trying to create a zip file with a symbolic link.
I have a subfolder in my mainfolder with some.bundle. I create symbolic link for this some.bundle which is placed in another subfolder of mainfolder.
I then zip it using Terminal.

My problem is when I open the zip via Terminal and then try to copy the bundle to some other folder using the symbolic link. It doesn't works.

It gives an error something like this..

```
cp:/path to my subfolder with bundle symbolic link/some.bundle No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try tar'ing it before zipping

Comment: I want it in zip only. I am using some other application and it requires only zip file.Thank you.

Comment: @John Did you use `zip -y ... ...` to zip the softlink? I hope I've understood your question correctly...

Comment: I have used this command zip --symlinks -r foo.zip foo/ My problem is i want to open the some.bundle from the zip file via symlink.Sorry,if my question was not clear. :)

Comment: I have also tried using a software known as symlinker from this page http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/41493/symlinker

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing, but if I understand you, you have a soft link to a zip'd file you wish to copy. As the zip is a normal file, you don't need to specify the -R option unless you want to copy an entire directory. Passing the -L flag will force cp to follow symbolic links in the SOURCE arg and place the regular file in DEST. Take a look [here](http://superuser.com/questions/138587/how-to-copy-symbolic-links) for more

Comment: Do you mean that the symlink no longer works when the *original* is not in the expected place? If you make the original structure in for instance ~/Desktop/myFolder/theOriginal then that's where the symbolic link will be looking for its source file, not in the relative location in the extracted zip. Only way I've found to deal with that is http://superuser.com/questions/1004535/mac-alias-linking-breaks-after-unzipping-the-folder/1004765#1004765 which I admit is a far from perfect solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following to check/solve this (but I don't really know if I understand the question/the problem correctly):

[image]

1. Create a file.bundle with

   ```
   touch /Users/user/temp/step1/file.bundle
   ```
2. Create a symlink in another folder

   ```
   ln -s /Users/user/temp/step1/file.bundle /Users/user/temp/step2/
   ```

   the (re-transcribed) hex content of the symlink is:

   ```
   /Users/user/temp/step1/file.bundle
   ```
3. Zip the symlink

   ```
   zip -y /Users/user/temp/step3file.bundle.zip /Users/user/temp/step2/file.bundle`
   ```
4. Create a folder (step4), cd into it and unzip step3file.bundle.zip

   ```
   mkdir /Users/user/temp/step4
   cd /Users/user/temp/step4
   unzip /Users/user/temp/step3file.bundle.zip
   ```

   the (re-transcribed) hex content of the unzipped symlink in /Users/user/temp/step4/Users/user/temp/step2 is still:

   ```
   /Users/user/temp/step1/file.bundle
   ```
5. Copy file.bundle in folder step1 using the symlink in a subfolder of folder step4 into folder step5

   ```
   cd /Users/user/temp/step4/Users/user/temp/step2
   cp file.bundle /Users/user/temp/step5
   ```

The above steps work. You probably zipped the folder containing the symlink and/or got some paths/commands (and maybe some options) wrong.